# How to verify Postgres backup has been successful?

Tags: postgresql

What's the best way to verify that the backup and restore of a Postgres database has succeeded without issues?

I am using the following to backup/restore:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Ft db > database.tar
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -Ft database.tar
```

Comment: save output to logs and grep for errors?..

Comment: I could do that but not all "error" in the logs are errors. I was wondering if there's something like a result output that outlines number of operations run and number of failures.

Comment: all errors are errors. you can count operations and errors if you want. it is only to decide if some error is critical or not TO THIS CURRENT RESTORE

Comment: Use Verbose mode. This will display all messages and you can standard out this or dump to file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can say out of several years of experiences with different ways of doing PostgreSQL backups I have never seen corrupted dump. If there is some problem in `pg_dump` run job simply dies with some error message which you can find in postgresql system log - usually in `/var/log/postgresql` (if you do not log stderr into some your file)

But I have seen corrupted pg database due to disk errors and in this case `pg_dump` was not able to make a backup and crashed with weird error due to attempt to allocate too much shared memory. And this way we were alerted that something is wrong - because PostgreSQL did not show any other error regarding it.

Comment: Well, I transfered dump files between hosts without zipped, then sometimes, I got corruption data error when restored.

Comment: OK, true is we send backups from source instance into Google nearline storage and if needed we copy it from GS into target instance. AFAIK these transfers to and from GS using gsutil check if transfer was successful using checksums and repeat it if necessary. So maybe you should also consider to use checksums to avoid corruption during transfer. You know - bad things happen any time...